# How to authorize against powerbi service (https://api.powerbi.com)?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, authorization, powerbi

I am having difficulty authorizing and using the powerbi rest api in python 3.6. I have configured a server-side application in AAD with the appropriate permissions for the power bi service api, and have the below request to get a bearer token:

```
import requests as r
import json
import logging

url = 'https://login.windows.net/<tenantid>/oauth2/token?redirect_url=https://localhost:8081&resource=https%3a%2f%2fanalysis.windows.net%2fpowerbi%2fapi'


params=dict()
params["grant_type"] = client_credentials
params["client_secret"] = <client_secret>
params["client_id"] = <client_id>

token = json.loads(r.post(url=url, data=params))["access_token"]
```

This successfully returns a bearer token. However, reaching out to any powerbi endpoint (in my case, I want to discover groups), I get a `403 Forbidden` error. Am I requesting the wrong scope? Below request fails with `403 Forbidden` regardless of any changes to the url:

```
auth=dict()
auth["Authorization"]=f'Bearer {token}'
url='https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups'
groups=r.get(url=url, headers=auth)
```

I'm hoping I missed something trivial, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried first to use Postman and then convert it into python script ?

Comment: yes - i used postman to get to the point where I could return the bearer token, converted that to script, then did it again to try different urls with the auth token. still getting 403. The resource returned with the token is congruent t\with the graph resource - am i using the correct authority url? do I need to do additional config for the app within the workspaces in the Service themselves?